# Encrypt and Decrypt AES

Tags: php, html, encryption, cryptography, aes

I want to encrypt the original string after i click the `encrypt button` and inputs element will not clear and after i click the `decrypt` it will `decrypt`. My problem is after i click the `decrypt` there is no value to the `decrypt` only the encrypt is moving. Can someone help me about this?

here is the output after i click the `decrypt`.
[image]

here is my code.

```
<?php
/*
 * PHP mcrypt - Basic encryption and decryption of a string
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$secret_key = "thisismykey12345";
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);

if(isset($_POST['encrypt'])){
    $string = $_POST['ostring'];

$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

}
else if(isset($_POST['decrypt'])){
    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post"> 
Original String <input type="text" name="ostring" value="<?php echo $string; ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" name="encrypt" value="Encrypt"><br>
Encrypted String <input type="text" style="width:500px;" name="encrypted" value="<?php echo $encrypted_string; ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" name="encrypt" value="Decrypt"><br>
Decrypted String <input type="text" style="width:500px" name="decrypted" value="<?php echo $decrypted_string; ?>"><br>
</form> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem is every time when you hit any submit button your whole data is resubmitted and encrypted string again and again reincryted

Comment: People are not responding, sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part has 2 logical flaws:

```
if(isset($_POST['encrypt'])){
    $string = $_POST['ostring'];
    $encrypted_string = ...;
}
else if(isset($_POST['decrypt'])){
    $decrypted_string = ...$encrypted_string...;
}
```

1. `$decrypted_string` will never be set because it relies on `$encrypted_string`. But `$encrypted_string` only exists if the execution path enters the first `if` block and skips the `elseif` block.
2. Besides you never check whether `ostring` is available before encrypting even though it's required

Put the two execution paths in separate `if` blocks:

```
if(isset($_POST['encrypt'],$_POST['ostring'])){
    $encrypted_string = ...;
}

if(isset($_POST['decrypt'],$encrypted_string)){
    $decrypted_string = ...;
}
```